# A quick rebus for the children

Tags: rebus

As a parent, it might happen to tell this at the partner:

[image: Rebus]

**`(3, 3, 7, 4)`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's

> ARE YOU KIDDING KIDS?

Because

> **R U** sounds like ''are you'', the baby face is ''kid'' and bell sounds like ''ding'', Key+DS = Kids

Comment: Yeah, that's it, nice one :)

Comment: @xKobalt I thought of this, but discarded it as it's using the same word twice and it doesn't seem to be something to say "at the partner" as you said.

Comment: @Randal'Thor well, I'll keep this on mind for the next times, thank you for the advice

Answer (score 7):

I think it's

> ARE YOU TENDING KIDS?

Because

> **R** **U** is self-explanatory, the baby-face seems to come from a cartoon for "TEN in the Bed" (?), the bell goes DING, and the last thing is KEY+DS ~ KIDS.

Comment: Woah, I'm surprised about the cartoon link, this answer is very nice, but I'm sorry to say that's not the one I expected (anyway it was a nice try because it's almost right)

Comment: @xKobalt It's easy to get almost right; the only difficult part is the face next to the bell :-)